# What is the best way for me to animate random objects in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation

I am currently developing a game for OS X using Cocoa where a spacecraft flies through space dodging/shooting asteroids.
 The asteroids appear at top of screen and fly vertically downwards until they disappear.

I have so far animated the asteroids such that all the different forms that will be implemented in the game appear at once and move from random points at the top of the screen vertically to the bottom of the screen until they are gone.
However I want to make it so that random asteroid types appear & animate, at random times, in multiple quantities (I need multiple NSImage/NSImageViews of the same type flying on screen also), and at different speeds/sizes.

Here is my animation code:

```
        // Prepare asteroids.
    _asteroiddark = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
    [_asteroiddark setImage: [NSImage imageNamed:@"asteroiddark"]];


    _asteroidlight = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
    [_asteroidlight setImage: [NSImage imageNamed:@"asteroidwhite"]];
    [_asteroidlight setFrame: theModel.lightAstRect];

    _asteroidsmall = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
    [_asteroidsmall setImage: [NSImage imageNamed:@"asteroidsmall"]];
    [_asteroidsmall setFrame: theModel.smallAstRect];

    _comet = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
    [_comet setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"comet.tif"]];
    [_comet setFrame: theModel.cometRect];



   // Set up key Processing timer for fluid spaceship movement.
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(processKeys) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    // Set up key Processing timer for animation.
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(myAnimations) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



    // Start animations.
    [self myAnimations];
  }


-(void) myAnimations
{

asteroids = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:
             _asteroiddark, _asteroidlight, _asteroidsmall,
             _comet, nil];


 // randomize where the asteroids/comets appear.
int randX;

// So asteroids 'n' such are varying in size.
int randSize;

// Where the asteroids are initially positioned at top of view/window.
CGPoint startPoint;

for (NSImageView *view in asteroids) {


    randX = arc4random_uniform(self.bounds.size.width);

    randSize =  40 + arc4random() % (120-40+1);

    startPoint = CGPointMake(randX, self.bounds.size.height);


    // Add each asteroid / comet to the view after setting their respective random start points.
    [view setFrame: NSMakeRect(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, randSize, randSize)];
    [self addSubview:view];

    // Create animation (down y-axis)
    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    [context setDuration:2.5];

    [context setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction  functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
    view.animator.frame = CGRectOffset(view.frame, 0, -self.bounds.size.height - 180);
    } completionHandler:nil];
}
}
```

Randomizing size and location is not the issue.

What is the most efficient way I can achieve random asteroids?

Am I better off using NSAnimation or should I be using Core Animation?

At the moment it is just wave after wave of the same objects appearing at different x points.

I am thinking I could randomize multiple timers so that they change their selector and interval and have multiple animation methods for selectors.
I could perhaps have methods animating one, two, three, four of the different asteroid types objects at a time, and a method for cloning imageviews.

The code above was implemented in a custom NSView.

Thanks!

Comment: Also keep in mind I intend to have collision detection.

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit ? You should, gives you collision detection for free and dynamics.

Comment: Can I not do collision detection the way I've done it?

Comment: Yes you can, but you will to manage it manually